# Does Ruby save certain files in IRB so "load" does not load a separate version of the file everytime?

Tags: ruby, irb

```
class Carnivore
  def roar=(v)
    @roar = v
  end

  def roar
    @roar
  end
end

  trex = Carnivore.new
  trex.roar = "GRRRxxz"
  puts trex.roar
```

OS Used: Windows 10.

I am using IRB and playing around with some of the getter/setter methods. If I delete the setter method `roar=(v)`, the reader method still works and will print out "GRRRxxz". However, if I quit IRB and launch another session, IRB will give me an error. Note that I am loading the files each time using the load keyword i.e.: `load "test.rb"`.

What's even more unusual is that if I update the `puts` after deleting the setter method, it will update the `puts` to whatever (i.e.: set GRRRxxz to YOOO, it will change to YOOO).

Can someone explain to me why IRB is operating in this manner? It seems to be saving the setter method for some inexplicable reason. It also does the same thing if you delete the reader method (will still work if you delete writer method, but an exiting and rebooting of IRB makes it fail).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IRB has nothing to do with this. It's a feature of ruby called "open classes"

So when you first load your `Carnivore` class, it is loaded in its entirety, because it didn't exist before. But if you then remove a method in a file and reload it, what happens is ruby **opens** your class and adds a getter method. Which it already had, so it's overwritten. Which explains why changes to method bodies (your `puts` there) are reflected.

This technique is what powers so-called "monkey-patching". You can patch any class in ruby, even a system one.

```
class String
  def pirate
    self + ', arrrr!'
  end
end

'hello'.pirate # => "hello, arrrr!"
```

You see, it "patches" an existing class. If this class definition replaced/shadowed the one from the system, your app would be pretty broken.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. You're saying when I delete the setter class, Ruby opens my class and adds a getter method (which it already has (`def roar`)), so it overwrites it . But that doesn't explain how Ruby saved the setter method. So I'm wondering where does the setter method come from, so that the getter method can access that variable?

Comment: @the12: follow me here. 1) you load full class, with getter and setter. 2) you remove a setter from the file. 3) you load the file again. 3.1) ruby opens the class and replaces the getter. But the setter is __already there__, from the first load.

Comment: Oh ok... So Ruby saves the setter method, so even by deleting it from the file and reloading it without the setter method, Ruby saves the setter method from the previous load?

Comment: @the12: not that ruby "saves" the setter. Take a look from this angle: a setter method is _created_ at first load. And since it's not present in the file when you load a second version of the class, the existing method in memory is not touched.

Comment: Ok it is in memory. Alright got it. Thanks for your help @Sergio Tulentsev!